# DDoS Attack Protection

Tags: ddos

Recently I've been threatened with an IP Address DDoS attack. I was wondering in what ways and how could I stop this attack. I'd really like to be able to do this without my parents finding out.

Comment: Your ISP is the only one who can - just call their support number

Comment: Related: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/56568/can-someone-launch-a-dos-attack-on-my-ip

Answer (score 2):

If you are on a home connection the best solution is to restart or turn off your router for 5 minutes so you get a new IP address from your ISP ...if you still get ddossed because of skype or another program  IP grabbing use a VPN or contact your ISP about the problem